# Mongodb: Is there an opposite to operator 'match'?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Currently looking to streamline some code and was wondering if there is a way to pull of the opposite of 'match'? By this I mean: is there a way to you make it so in a pipeline you select all documents that do not match your match query? I've been looking for a bit and have yet to find an answer (there probably might be one somewhere, I'm just awful when it comes to using the right terminology).

Comment: `$match` works basically with query operators just like `.find()` does but in an aggregation context. If you want "negation" then you want a "query operator" to do that. So [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) or [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) as depends on the context. Not a different pipeline stage, just different operators. Do yourself a favor and use the sidebar links from those pages to discover all the other operators and what they do.

Answer (score 0):

there is no complete opposite of $match but
you can always use $nin

i guess you are looking for like aggregate those which does not match the condition

you can use like this

code

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            yourmatchCondition: {
                $nin: [yourStatement]
            }
        }
    }
])
```